# how do i switch a condition based on bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a sql query which has a condition in where clause like below:

```
select target_name from target_properties where host_name in
(select target_name from target_metric A 
join TARGET_MEMBERS B on A.TARGET_NAME = B.MEMBER_TARGET_NAME
where METRIC_COLUMN = 'usage' and AGGREGATE_TARGET_NAME like :oem_group)
and install_time  < (sysdate-90)
```

How can i make a change to this so that if the bind variable :oem_group contains 'PROD' then use the condition 'install_time  < (sysdate-90)' ,else use the condition 'install_time  < (sysdate-30)'
Im unsure of the usage of 'case' here.

Comment: `install_time < (sysdate - case when :oem_group like '%PROD%' then 90 else 30 end)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a case statement

```
and install_time  < (case when :oem_group like '%PROD%' then (sysdate-90) else (sysdate-30) end)
```

If you wish to handle this using `and` `or`

```
where...    and (:oem_group like '%PROD%' and install_time < (sysdate-90)) 
                 or (:oem_group not like '%PROD%' and install_time < (sysdate-30))
```